# How do I reset the value of a text input when the page reloads?

Tags: javascript, html

Firefox (and probably other browsers) want to keep whatever text the user entered in the text input, even after a reload. Just including the default text (that I want the input to revert to) in the html doesn't work:

```
<input tyep='text' value='default text' />
```

And neither does trying to use JS

```
window.onload = function() {document.getElementById("mytextinput").value = 'default text'}
```

Comment: it should be <input type="text" name="foo" value="bar" />

Comment: you can just switch off autocomplete in browsers (that support it)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use plain old HTML :)

Set `autocomplete='off'`  in the attribute

```
<input type='text' value='default text' autocomplete='off' />
```

This works on most modern browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you don't have to run a function onload to clear it--you could just put the javascript right in the page.  For instance:

```
document.getElementById("mytextinput").value = ''
```

or with jQuery

```
$("mytextinput").val('');
```

Note that it's always a good idea to work with a dom listener to ensure that your javascript fires after the dom has been properly built.  So, in the example of jQuery, this would be as easy as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("mytextinput").val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type='text' id='mytextinput' value='default text' />
<script>
    document.getElementById("mytextinput").value = 'default text';
</script>
```

This code should run as soon as the textbox has loaded.  The onload event can seem inconsistent, I'm not entirely sure how it behaves in multiple browsers on different actions like refreshing.

You can call the script differently, put it in a function, put it somewhere else etc, but it's good to start with a working version.

If this doesn't work on other browsers there isn't much you can do because some browsers will try and be 'helpful' and always autofill for you.

Comment: This wouldn't work...not only because your type is spelled 'tyep' but because there's no ID assigned to the input field.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do a server side coding on page reload. Page reload is generally a postback type idea . The page gets reloaded from server. If you are doing asp.net , in page_load method add your default text. :)