# header location delay

Tags: php

I have the following php code which I want to add a delay too:

```
<?php
    echo "Message has been sent.";
    header("Location: page2.php", true, 303);
    exit;
?>
```

The above code happens too fast so I can't see the message:

I have tried:

```
<?php
    sleep(5);
    echo "Message has been sent.";
    header("Location: page2.php", true, 303);
    exit;
?>
```

This doesn't display the message either, but it does sleep for 5 seconds, which is just a waste of time.

How do I get it to display a message for 5 second before redirecting?

Comment: I assume you put the echo first (maye a flush of the buffer) and THEN sleep, instead of first sleep and then echo?!

Comment: It's because the sleep is happening on the server, and you want the delay to happen on the client, right? You'll need to use javascript to make the delay happen.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You cannot do this with a HTTP location redirect, as this redirect will happen as soon as the browser gets the header. Instead, use a refresh redirect in the header:

```
header( "Refresh:5; url=http://www.example.com/page2.php", true, 303);
```

This *should* work on modern browsers, however it is not standardized, so to get the equivalent functionality would be do use a meta refresh redirect (meaning you'd have to output a full HTML too):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.example.com/page2.php">
```

From [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_refresh):

> Used in redirection, or when a new resource has been created. This
>   refresh redirects after X seconds. This is a proprietary, non-standard
>   header extension introduced by Netscape and supported by most web
>   browsers.

Comment: I cannot find the `Refresh` header in the HTTP specification. Is this standardized?

Comment: It is not standardized, however I'm trying to find a browser that does not support it (I'm sure there's one). In any case, the alternative to this is a `<meta>` refresh, which yields similar functionality

Comment: @nickb Yes, IE11 :-)

Answer (score 3):

Do the redirect using client-side scripting:

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = 'page2.php';
  }, 5000);
</script>
<p>Message has been sent.</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to modify your code like this:

```
<?php

    echo "Message has been sent.";
    sleep(5);
    header("Location: page2.php", true, 303);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, @nickb method worked for me though.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to see the message if you're using a header(Location) redirect. In fact, that redirect shouldn't work at all since output starts before the headers are sent. Instead, you should echo a meta tag refresh with a delay, like this
`echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=\'http://example.com/\'">';`
which will have a delay of five seconds. Alternatively, (and more properly) you could output a JS redirect, as the meta refresh tag is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if it helps but as i was dealing with the same issue in a form which need to be clean after the submission of the message, i found this answer that explains that you could change the value input to be empty.

This is the answer:
[How do I reset the value of a text input when the page reloads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502305/how-do-i-reset-the-value-of-a-text-input-when-the-page-reloads)

and this is how i fix my issue, using my class .form-control

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".form-control").val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header( "Refresh:time; url='filelocation'");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me... I'm using the latest PHP version 7.3.3 on WAMPP for Windows...

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'] ?? null; 

if(empty(trim($name))){
    header("location: http://localhost/testsite/index.php");
}

echo 'Greetings '. $_POST['name'].', how can I help you?';

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=\'http://localhost/testsite/index.php\'">';
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
echo "<div class='form'>
                  <h3>Added successfully.</h3><br/>
                  </div>";
                  
                $time_out = 05; //here you set how many seconds to untill refresh
header("refresh: $time_out; url=insert.php");  
       ?>
```