# how to redirect html page form php page?

Tags: php, html, email

Two files `index.html` and `mail_handler.php`
from this code that open `mail_handler.php` file but I don't want to open that file direct open HTML file `index.html` with a message.

> submitted !!

After seeing a quick `"email sent`" message, I'd like the user to be directed back to the `index.html` page from `mailhandler_auto.php`.

mail_handler.php

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $name=$_POST['name'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $phone=$_POST['subject'];
            $msg=$_POST['msg'];

            $to='xyz@yahoo.com'; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID
            $subject='Form Submission';
            $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Subject :".$subject."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;
            $headers="From: ".$email;

    enter code here
            if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo '<script>alert("insert successfull");</script>';
          }
            else{
                echo "Something went wrong!";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

This is `index.html` file i have used action method but in this code that move on `mail_handler.php` page but i want to go `index.html` page 
index.html

```
    <form action="mail_handler.php" method="post" name="form" class="">
                  <div class="form-group ">
                    <div class="">
                      <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" required >
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="">
                      <input class="form-control input-lg" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address*" required >
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="">
                      <input class="form-control input-lg" type="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject*" required >
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="">
                      <textarea class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Message*" required  rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="">
                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="submit" value="send" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: if you just want to redirect your users back to your index.html page, you can use: `header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); `

Answer (score 1):

after sending the mail you can redirect the page in two ways

> 1) using JavaScript like your are using here to show the alert . Here you can simply add the script given below. It will redirect

```
window.open("index.html","_parent");
```

> 2) By using the PHP also you can do the same. Below is the example.Please add the script inside the if loop you can do

```
header('Location: index.html');
```

or

```
header('Location: ./');
```

Please try this.

Comment: The PHP version is one I like to use. It prevents problems with double submission. If you feel particularly brave, you can set header to $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: as your wish :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the header tags of html:

```
`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://www.example.com/page2.php">`
```

This will redirect it after 5 seconds. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299006/header-location-delay) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested in others answers, you can redirect via javascript with [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

```
window.open("index.html","_self");
```

or via php with [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

```
header('Location: index.html');
```

Also you have the option to do everything in the same file:

```
$message=NULL;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['subject'];
    $msg=$_POST['msg'];

    $to='xyz@yahoo.com'; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID
    $subject='Form Submission';
    $message="Name :".$name."\n"."Phone :".$phone."\n"."Subject :".$subject."\n"."Wrote the following :"."\n\n".$msg;
    $headers="From: ".$email;


    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        $message= '<script>alert("insert successfull");</script>';
    }
    else{
        $message "Something went wrong!";
    }
}


<form action="index.php" method="post" name="form" class="">
<div class="form-group ">
    <div class="">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" required >
    </div><br>
    <div class="">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address*" required >
    </div><br>
    <div class="">
        <input class="form-control input-lg" type="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject*" required >
    </div><br>
    <div class="">
        <textarea class="form-control" name="msg" placeholder="Message*" required  rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
    </div><br>
    <div class="">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="submit" value="send" name="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can create a condition

```
if ($message) {
    echo $message;
    } else {
//show the form
}
```

To show the form or the message

Note that using all the logic in one file could be easier and quicker but is prone to duplicate sending when refreshing the page.

Have a look at [Post/Redirect/Get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)  to know more

Comment: I don't like this approach, since if you press F5 (and users at some point will), the data is resubmitted, which can cause multiple problems.

Comment: this is not the answer

Comment: You are both right. I just updated the answer with more information

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  echo '<script>location.replace("index.html");</script>';
```