# php,javascript:ajax Form email action and validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have tried using a action="mail.site.com", info@site.com, and the page just refreshes without sending the query form.I think I need a PHP or Ajax page to send the email to the server and give the user a response. I have tried a few things I am not skilled at PHP. If anyone has any insight it would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

```html
<section style="background: url(_images/pattern.html)" class="reservation parallax-repeat dark">
            <div class=reservation__inner>
                <div class=container>
                    <div class=row>
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">
                            <header class=section-header>
                                <h2>Servicio de reservas</h2>
                                <div class=divider></div>
                                <p>
                                    Para que el mantenimiento de su vehículo sea rápido y sin complicaciones, le recomendamos encarecidamente que realice una reserva en línea. Es completamente gratis y no te llevará mucho tiempo.</header>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class=reservation-form>
                        <form id=reservForm action=# method=POST data-toggle=validator>
                            <div class=reservation-form__center-wrapper>
                                <div class="form-group item-1">
                                    <label for=resName class=label-control>Tu Nombre</label>
                                    <div class="input-wrap input-wrap--icon-left"><i class="input-icon pe-7s-user"></i>
                                        <input id=resName type=text name=field_name placeholder="David Kraemer" required class=form-control>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group item-2">
                                    <label for=resNumber class=label-control>Su Teléfono</label>
                                    <div class="input-wrap input-wrap--icon-left"><i class="input-icon pe-7s-phone"></i>
                                        <input id=resNumber type=tel name=field_tel placeholder="+1 (812) 281 55 23" required class=form-control>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group item-3">
                                    <label for=resDate class=label-control>Fecha</label>
                                    <div class="input-wrap input-wrap--icon-left"><i class="input-icon pe-7s-date"></i>
                                        <input id=resDate type=text name=field_date placeholder=09/18/2016 required class="form-control pick-date">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group item-4">
                                    <label for=resTime class=label-control>Hora</label>
                                    <div class=input-wrap><i class="input-icon fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                        <input id=resTime type=text name=field_time placeholder=16:30 required class="form-control time-pick">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button type=submit class="btn btn-regular btn-accent"><span class=btn-text>
Hacer una reserva</span><span class=btn-over></span></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: `form id="reservForm" action="anyfile.php" method="POST" data-toggle="validator">`

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly I appreciate your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can see that you have the html form constructed, the part you are missing will be adding the url where the form data will be processed.

```
<form id=reservForm action="sendemail.php" method=POST data-toggle=validator>
```

Once done you need to create a sendemail.php file and to access the user data that the user keyed the php code will look like this:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['field_name'];
    $tel = $_POST['field_tel'];
    $date = $_POST['field_date'];
    $time = $_POST['field_time'];
?>
```

After obtaining the data, you need to validate each of them to see if the type formats is what you want. Try reading [form validation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_validation_example.htm)

Last but not least, if everything is alright then you can proceed to send the email using the sample code below:

```
<?php

  $to = "abc@domain.com";
  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

You can read more about sending email [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp).

Comment: Vincent I still can't get this to work.  I need to create a form to interact with my html/css/js theme. The script css and js have been minified and when beautify I still cannot fix the problem. I want to use theme contact form using POST to send and then confirm with message sent conformation. I want to use theme contact form using POST to send and then confirm with Thank you message sent conformation using theme styling and then return to previous page.
 Here is the theme I am using http://netgon.ru/themeforest/carros_html/

Comment: Do you mean after you minified your code the form stops working or does it works before you minified?

Comment: The theme came only with the css and js  minifed files. Also the index.html pages is set to no=JS here is a link to a test site running the template.http://vineblock.trade/

Comment: I can get the email to submit and send but then the screen goes blank after.  I confirmed the email is received at my server.  I want the form to send and to prompt a validate message"Your message has been sent." with the template styling and returning the user to the page Should I do this with Ajax? Any help you can provide would be great. Willing to make a donation via Paypal to solve this isuue. Thanks

Comment: For the message sent, there are few ways to do it. The easiest way would be redirecting the page to a success page with your your message and style using header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/success.php"); exit(); after you sent the email.

Comment: No need for the donation but appreciate if you can mark my post as correct and vote up if you find them useful

Comment: Thank you soo much Vincent! I am using /mail/mail.php.  Should I add the success.php in the mail folder as well? include ("Location: yourwebsite.com/success.php"); exit(); to mail.php and then ad below to success.php?         Process form

// If processing was successful, redirect
if($success)
{

// Replace your redirection URL here
    header("Location: http://vineblock.trade");
}

Comment: It depends what outcome you want to achieve, normally you will add `header("Location......")` right after `mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);`, so that you will be greet with success page after submission. After being greet for 5 seconds you want the page to auto redirect back to home page, then you will need to add another `header( "Refresh:5; url=http://www.yourwebsite.com", true, 303);` in your success page but with delay. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299006/header-location-delay

Comment: Vincent, thanks for your time I really appreciate all your help.  Now the forms are being sent, the success.php. is redirecting the user back to vineblock.trade after 3 seconds.  The problem now is the forms received at my server are blank.  No data fields are being processed. Also the success page doesn't provide a "message sent" validation to the user.

Comment: I am so close to fixing this with your help. I have spent approximately 12 hours over the last 2 days working on this.  I can usually fix most problems but this  theme only providing Minified CSS & JS  made this process a nightmare. Even after Beautify  js.minify is 16000 lines!

Comment: i tried to run Eslint to no avail in Brackets and Atom. http://vineblock.trade with the changes if you could please view the site and try to fill out and submit form and provide further input I would be indebted to you. I apologize for multiple comments I don't have chat ability yet on stackoverflow.  Thanks

Comment: Ok lets solve the receiving email issue, since you are receiving the email, now you need to ensure that the data being send across.
Have you attached `<?php
    $name = $_POST['field_name'];
    $tel = $_POST['field_tel'];
    $date = $_POST['field_date'];
    $time = $_POST['field_time'];
?>` to capture the data?

Comment: i added the fields as necessary.  I will gladly send you the files to help. I don't have chat enabled yet can i email  or message you? I am wondering if in that reserv form there is no email field perhaps because there is no email the reserv form maybe that is conflicting? I want to add an email to the reserv form anyway.