# How can I redirect my Window page to another URL from the ajax called php function, I dont want to redirect it from jQuery or javascript

Tags: php, ajax, redirect

I have a main page url localhost/php/coadlines/home.php and hiting an ajax localhost/php/coadlines/processAjax.php but in processAjax.php page I want to some redirection function, so that My main page url ie.localhost/php/coadlines/home.php redirect to localhost/php/coadlines/index.php.
I dont want to write any redirection function in ajax success callback function like (window.location.replace()).

NOTE:ALL i need to do redirect it from PHP only dont want to do it from jQuery and javascript redirection.

Comment: You **can not** redirect the front end, via the HTTP response to a background request. If you don’t want to do this using JS on the client - well then you have to stop using AJAX for this request in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: you already finished sending the page, and it's in the browser's control now. If you want to add information (like a redirect), you have to do it using the javascript that's running on that page.

As a workaround, you might be able to instruct the first page to redirect after a delay, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11299053/854080). This is not-standard, not guaranteed to work, and does not guarantee that the ajax request finishes, but it *might* work for you use case. But if in any possible: use javascript.

Comment: I know it is not a good practice, but I was stuck in such a case as I am using dataGrid library to show datatable which is sending the response on the server from API but did not find any  callback success function (did R&D), in which I need to put redirect things, That Is why I am looking to redirect on index.php page  in  PHP only.