# Why wont the highlighted If statement evaluate? Var_Dump is returning true but the redirect won't work. When Query has results, rest of code is Okay

Tags: php, mongodb, cursor

The If statement below is not evaluating when there is no matching `$searchname` in the mongo database. However, when supplied with `$searchname` that is available in the database, the rest of the code runs okay.
This is what the browser developer's console is showing ( Navigated to 127.0.0.1/*****/searchByNameResults.php searchByNameResults.php:1 Failed to launch 'location:%20searchbyname.php' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.)

```
$filter = ['employee_name' => $searchname ];
$option = [];
$read = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $option);
$query = $conn->executeQuery("$dbname.$collection", $read);
                
var_dump($query->isDead());  
    
if ($query->isDead() === true){    //if the query has no matching result          
  //if (strlen($queryresult[$employee_name])==0):
            
  // if($queryresult->employee_name!==$searchname):
  $error = "No Voip Contact with the name provided. Try a different name.";
       
  header("refresh:3; Location: searchbyname.php"); // Redirect to searchbynamepage 
  exit;
} 
else {
  foreach ($query as $queryresult): 
  ?>    
    <div class="table-container">
      <?php echo "<table>"; 
      ?>
```

Comment: Just because the redirect didn't work doesn't mean that the code didn't enter the `if ($query->isDead() === true){ ` block. Have you checked _inside_ that block to see what statements are executed, if any? But if there is any output (including var_dump output) before the `header` command, it will never work. Headers _must_ be the first thing your script outputs. Maybe that's the issue. Do you get any warnings logged? Does the response to the browser contain the Location header or not (you can use your browser's Network tool to see this)?

Comment: @ADyson - This is what the browser is showing ( Navigated to http://127.0.0.1/directra/searchByNameResults.php
searchByNameResults.php:1 Failed to launch 'location:%20searchbyname.php' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.)

Comment: Thanks but you need to [edit] your question to show any important info like this, don't hide it in the comments :-)

Comment: Thank you @ADyson  for pointing what the error was. The if statement was evaluating but the header redirect  was the problem. What I haven't figured out now is how to take the user to the intended page when the if statement evaluates to true.

Comment: I think the syntax of your header command is wrong. You're probably looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299006/header-location-delay . P.S. You forgot to edit the question