# How to prevent auto insert data when refresh page

Tags: javascript, php

When I insert data and I refresh page It will auto insert old data

I try use header location :

```
if (!empty($msg_success)) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $msg_success . '")</script>';
        header('location:'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit();
    }
```

It's work but It didnt echo alert! before refresh page

How can I echo alert before reload page ? or Is there anyway to prevent insert data when refresh page ?

#### UPDATE

when I refresh page I've  `$_POST['submit']` that why my data keep insert when I refresh

Comment: You cannot return an HTML response (which would trigger the alert) *and* redirect at the same time via HTTP headers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [displaying a message after redirecting the user to another web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249906/displaying-a-message-after-redirecting-the-user-to-another-web-page)

Comment: Possible already answered in [Stackkoverflow How do I reset the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502305/how-do-i-reset-the-value-of-a-text-input-when-the-page-reloads)

Comment: unset all post/get values before header call

Answer (score 0):

In html you can set an attribute on the input in question to nullify autocomplete.

Set autocomplete attribute to "off"

`<input type='text' value='default text' autocomplete='off' />`

Comment: not wroking still insert data when i refresh page with $_POST['submit']